# Maximum call stack size exceeded Kendo Ui

Tags: jquery, ajax, kendo-ui

I make a call to my jquery function after a client select and I find myself with this problem :

```
kendo.all.js:5282 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Function (<anonymous>)
at o.filter (kendo.all.js:5282)
at kendo.all.js:5303
at U (kendo.all.js:4901)
at o.select (kendo.all.js:5243)
at o.group (kendo.all.js:5302)
at Function.o.process (kendo.all.js:5473)
at init._queryProcess (kendo.all.js:6877)
at init._process (kendo.all.js:6867)
at init._change (kendo.all.js:6834)
```

I found that in all the lines with the set () function I get this error, but when I change the function with a (=) and fetch of my grid the problem is terminated, I do not know c ' Is what the solution, I will assemble you a part of my code

```
function GetplanFormation1() {
    var prj = $("#prj").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',`
        url: UrlRoot + 'Formation/readPlanFormation?client=' + cl + "&projet=" + prj,

        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
                var dataItem = DSThemeFormation.get(data[i].id);
                console.log("data", data);

                if (data[i].PrjAct) {
                    dataItem.checked = true;
                    dataItem.nbj = data[i].j;
                    dataItem.id_org = data[i].org;

                }
                else {
                    dataItem.idP = data[i].idP;
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            if (prj == undefined) {
            }
            if (cl == undefined) {
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Saad, This seem to be a problem related with your kendo widget, can you please  include the part of the code where the kendo widget is created?, because without it is very hard to guess what is happening

Comment: <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.1.226/kendo.common-Material.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: This is the import of the kendo library, i need the code where you create your kendo dropdown, autocomplete or grid (whatever control you are using)

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`set()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject#methods-set) method of the dataItem will trigger the [`change`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-change) event of the Grid dataSource instance, which in turn will rebind the Grid. That's why, calling `set()` a large number of times for granular data item updates is bad for the performance and causes the JavaScript error.

I recommend populating a standalone array of plain objects in the `success` callback, and then assign the whole array as a new Grid dataSource via the dataSource's [`data()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-data) method. In this way you will only have one `change` event firing, and one Grid rebind.